# MVC 3 ContentResult binary file with firefox strange issue

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-3, file-io

I've got an MVC 3 app that allows users to upload files with some data entry stuff. I've set up a controller that fetches those documents and buffers them out to the user like so

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 1200, VaryByParam = "id")]
public ContentResult GetNarrative(int id)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    var narrative = attachRepo.GetNarrative(id);
    if (narrative == null || narrative.Narrative == null)
        return null;

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
        string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", 
            Server.UrlEncode(narrative.Filename)));

    Response.OutputStream.Write(narrative.Narrative.ToArray(), 
        0, narrative.Narrative.ToArray().Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    return Content("");
}
```

This works fine and well, the interesting thing is that when I have the output cache line, my firefox download dialog looks like this

[image: open with chrome?]

However when I comment out the output cache line it looks like the expected dialog

[image: open in word like expected]

This isn't really a blocking issue, as it works just fine in IE and Chrome just downloads by default, but I am curious why this would be happening and if anyone has experienced this and worked around it.

Thanks!

Comment: With caching enabled does it still download correctly?

Comment: Yeah it downloads fine, if you try to open it (from the prompt), it opens in chrome and just displays binary data--it's very odd for sure. Opening in Windows after download works just fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that firefox ignores the filename in the Attachment.  It tends to use he URL to set the filename.

Try putting at the end of the URL ?filename.docx

And see if it fixes things.